# Summarise data by removing duplicates

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe with values:

```
x y value 
A B 10  
B A 15  
A C 5  
C A 10  
B C 20

df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B"),
                 y = c("A", "A", "C", "A", "C"),
                 value = c(10, 15, 5, 10, 20))
```

I would like to summarise this data to each combination of **x** and **y** and get the sum of the value per combination. The result would be:

```
x y value
A B 25  
A C 15  
B C 20
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30103871/1053718) which is more or less the same question as I have. But the solutions don't work in my case. This is because the values in **x** and **y** are strings and `min()` and `max()` won't work.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: The provided data set and the reproducible code vary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `sort` the rows in the first two columns and replace it, use `aggregate` to get the `sum` of 'value' by the groups 'x' and 'y'.

```
df[1:2] <- t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort))
aggregate(value~., df, sum)
#  x y value
# 1 A B    25
# 2 A C    15
# 3 B C    20
```

Comment: Was writing exactly the same thing but couldn't get the desired output. Apparently OP showed and gave different data sets. This seems like a dupe though

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I had the same problem, but then I copied the data that was showed and got the correct answer.  May be he had a typo.  Sure, it looks like a dupe.

Comment: Ok, got a dupe by searching your answers again