# R - Is there a vectorized way/premade function that is fast to generate unique sets between two vectors?

Tags: r, performance, unique, vectorization, combinations

So, what I want is a dataframe where the combinations of two random vectors are represented on the row. I do not want duplicate combinations like; 1,2;2,1. Just 1 of them. As well as the combination NOT being self-repeating; 1,1.

Right now I got this simple for loop, but it is not ideal;

```
unique_combos <- function(v1, v2) {
    df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2))
    counter = 0
    for (name1 in v1) {
        for (name2 in v2) {
            if (name1 != name2){
                counter = counter + 1
                df[counter,] <- c(name1, name2)
            }
        }
    }
    return(df)
}

# example usage;
> v1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
> v2 <- c(3,4,5,6)
> unique_combos(v1, v2)
   X1 X2
1   1  3
2   1  4
3   1  5
4   1  6
5   2  3
6   2  4
7   2  5
8   2  6
9   3  4
10  3  5
11  3  6
12  4  3
13  4  5
14  4  6
>
```

Any vectorized way to do this? Preferably aimed towards performance as well.
Besides this I wanted to note that the vectors can be any length and will contain random variables.

Edit1 - **my function does not work properly!**; I don't want the 3-4 4-3 combination.

Edit2 - My final solution by both @Ryan and @Frank (thanks guys!);

```
unique_combos <- function(v1, v2) {
  intermediate <- unique(CJ(v1, v2)[V1 > V2, c("V1", "V2") := .(V2, V1)])
  return(intermediate[V1 != V2])
```

*note; this does use the packages `data.table` and `plyr`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for loops at all.
You can use `expand.grid` and have the data.frame, with repeats, in one instruction. Then with a logical index keep only the different rows.

```
unique_combos2 <- function(v1, v2) {
  e <- expand.grid(v1, v2)
  e <- e[e[[1]] < e[[2]], ]
  e[order(e[[1]]), ]
}


u1 <- unique_combos(v1, v2)
u2 <- unique_combos2(v1, v2)
```

Now the speed tests. First with your data, then with larger vectors. I will load packages `microbenchmark` and `ggplot2`  to run the tests and visualize the results.

(Results not shown.)

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

mb1 <- microbenchmark(
  u1 = unique_combos(v1, v2),
  u2 = unique_combos2(v1, v2)
)

mb1
autoplot(mb1)

w1 <- 1:20
w2 <- sample(100, 30)

mb2 <- microbenchmark(
  u1 = unique_combos(w1, w2),
  u2 = unique_combos2(w1, w2)
)

mb2
autoplot(mb2)
```

Comment: I edited my post, the combinations aren't right! See the 3-4 4-3 combination. I want to avoid this kind of behavior and just have 1 instead of both.

Comment: @CasperPetersBerghopper It's now with Frank's idea of using `<`. I think this corrects it.

Answer (score 2):

The speed difference here probably won't have any real impact unless your vectors are huge, but since you put "performance" as a tag, here's a slightly faster method.

```
library(data.table)
CJ(v1, v2)[V1 != V2]
```

Benchmark:

Note:
`CJ` will order by `v1` by default, and ordering by `v1` in `unique_combos2` takes a lot of time, so I removed that part since it's not clear you need it.

```
unique_combos2 <- function(v1, v2) {
  e <- expand.grid(v1, v2)
  e <- e[e[[1]] != e[[2]], ]
  e
}
unique_combos3 <- function(v1, v2) CJ(v1, v2)[V1 != V2]

w1 <- sample(200)
w2 <- sample(200)
mb2 <- microbenchmark(
  u2 = unique_combos2(w1, w2),
  u3 = unique_combos3(w1, w2)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq        max neval cld
#    u2 5.513842 5.942765 10.969386 6.692507 8.158763 368.180211   100   b
#    u3 1.140513 1.443076  1.898202 1.711384 2.139075   8.397942   100  a
```

Edit: To remove duplicate pairs irrespective of order, use @Frank's solution in the comments, which effectively sorts all the rows before calling `unique`

```
unique(CJ(v1, v2)[V1 > V2, c("V1", "V2") := .(V2, V1)])
```

Comment: I edited my post, the combinations aren't right! See the 3-4 4-3 combination. I want to avoid this kind of behavior and just have 1 instead of both.
And no, I do not need an exact ordering of v1, I just need the combinations

Comment: @Caspar I guess using `>` or `<` in place of Ryan's `!=` (and ditto in the other answers) should fix that.

Comment: @Frank Thanks! Everything works now like I want it to :). I don't get why this works though, can you explain why using `>` or `<` fixes this?

Comment: The solution of using `>` or `<` is not quite right, because you could easily remove non-duplicate pairs as well that way, depending on the vectors. Just use the method in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028369/removing-duplicate-combinations-irrespective-of-order

Comment: Oh, good point Ryan. Another option would be `unique(CJ(v1, v2)[V1 > V2, c("V1", "V2") := .(V2, V1)])` @Caspar It works (at least in this latter formulation) by choosing a convention so either pairs V1 < V2 or V1 > V2 are kept.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` way, mostly using `purrr` tools. (edited to address clarification of the question). This method does the following:

1. Get a list of the product set of the vectors, filtering cases where they are equal,
2. Convert the list elements to sorted integer vectors, and discard any that are duplicates with `unique`,
3. `transpose` back to a list-of-columns structure, `simplify` to convert columns to vectors, and place back inside a data frame.

Very open to seeing if anyone can come up with a way to condense some steps!

```r
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
v2 <- c(3,4,5,6)
library(tidyverse)
cross2(v1, v2, .filter = `==`) %>%
  map(~ sort(as.integer(.))) %>%
  unique %>%
  transpose(.names = c("x", "y")) %>%
  simplify_all %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 13 x 2
#>        x     y
#>    <int> <int>
#>  1     1     3
#>  2     2     3
#>  3     3     4
#>  4     1     4
#>  5     2     4
#>  6     1     5
#>  7     2     5
#>  8     3     5
#>  9     4     5
#> 10     1     6
#> 11     2     6
#> 12     3     6
#> 13     4     6
```

Created on 2018-10-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Hi, I edited my post, thank you for pointing out the combinations still being present (my mistake). I do not necessarily need an ordering, I just want the unique combinations. To clarify; yes, I just want one of the combinations, does not matter which one.

Comment: Edited to address this clarification!