# splitstring and obtain all combinations of substrings after split value with only 1 item per combination can come from value before split

Tags: r

Here's the same task we solved in Python. I've tried utilizing a similar approach of creating an empty dictionary from pre-split (R's strsplit) keys and unpacking all corresponding post-split strings as values. Then, next step is to create all combinations but no more than one pre-split string can exist in the resulting combinations.

Here is my input list:

```
list('ROOM1-abc',
'ROOM1-def',
'ROOM2-abc',
'ROOM2-lol',
'ROOM3-whatever')
```

And the desired output (with 2-length combinations (needs to be able to pick the length of combination elements returned)):

```
['ROOM1-abc', 'ROOM2-lol'],
['ROOM1-abc', 'ROOM3-whatever'],
['ROOM1-def', 'ROOM2-abc'],
['ROOM1-def', 'ROOM2-lol'],
['ROOM1-def', 'ROOM3-whatever'],
['ROOM2-abc', 'ROOM3-whatever'],
['ROOM2-lol', 'ROOM3-whatever']]
```

I'm struggling with the sub-item list indexing syntax in Python vs. R as well as having to learn R for a specific need on a problem we've solved already via Python .

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the input.  Not clear about the the structure of the string.  May be you need `combn(unique(unlist(strsplit(str1, '"'))), 2)`

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right what you want to do is

```
df <- expand.grid(unlist(lst1), unlist(lst1))
df
             Var1           Var2
1       ROOM1-abc      ROOM1-abc
2       ROOM1-def      ROOM1-abc
3       ROOM2-abc      ROOM1-abc
4       ROOM2-lol      ROOM1-abc
5  ROOM3-whatever      ROOM1-abc
6       ROOM1-abc      ROOM1-def
7       ROOM1-def      ROOM1-def
8       ROOM2-abc      ROOM1-def
9       ROOM2-lol      ROOM1-def
10 ROOM3-whatever      ROOM1-def
11      ROOM1-abc      ROOM2-abc
12      ROOM1-def      ROOM2-abc
13      ROOM2-abc      ROOM2-abc
14      ROOM2-lol      ROOM2-abc
15 ROOM3-whatever      ROOM2-abc
16      ROOM1-abc      ROOM2-lol
17      ROOM1-def      ROOM2-lol
18      ROOM2-abc      ROOM2-lol
19      ROOM2-lol      ROOM2-lol
20 ROOM3-whatever      ROOM2-lol
21      ROOM1-abc ROOM3-whatever
22      ROOM1-def ROOM3-whatever
23      ROOM2-abc ROOM3-whatever
24      ROOM2-lol ROOM3-whatever
25 ROOM3-whatever ROOM3-whatever
```

This gives a matrix with *all* possible combinations. So the difference to the sugegstion of akrun is that this also gives you a combination with the element itself, e.g. ROOM1-abc | ROOM1-abc and cares about order, hence gives you for example ROOM3-whatever | ROOM1-abc and ROOM3-whatever | ROOM1-abc.

If you do not care about order you can remove rows with [`duplicate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028369/removing-duplicate-combinations-irrespective-of-order)

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))), ]
             Var1           Var2
1       ROOM1-abc      ROOM1-abc
2       ROOM1-def      ROOM1-abc
3       ROOM2-abc      ROOM1-abc
4       ROOM2-lol      ROOM1-abc
5  ROOM3-whatever      ROOM1-abc
7       ROOM1-def      ROOM1-def
8       ROOM2-abc      ROOM1-def
9       ROOM2-lol      ROOM1-def
10 ROOM3-whatever      ROOM1-def
13      ROOM2-abc      ROOM2-abc
14      ROOM2-lol      ROOM2-abc
15 ROOM3-whatever      ROOM2-abc
19      ROOM2-lol      ROOM2-lol
20 ROOM3-whatever      ROOM2-lol
25 ROOM3-whatever ROOM3-whatever
```

EDIT

```
# splits at "-"
split <- strsplit(unlist(lst1), "-")
# adds "-" to each vector
split2 <- lapply(split, function(x){
  c(x[1], "-", x[2])})
# saves everything as a dataframe (if desired)
do.call("cbind.data.frame", split2)
```

Comment: This is helpful but my mistake, I did not explicitly list the delimiter. My input is a list with two elements in each item and I need to delimit "-" such that "ROOM1-abc" is split into "ROOM1", "-", "abc" where "abc" is used to create combinations but no more than one "ROOM1" can exist in any combinations.

Comment: Thanks @schwantke. I am trying to use the comments to get my desired output. I don't mind if the end result resides in a list or data.frame as I can work it to how I need. Let me see if I can better explain this. If I need combinations of strings after the split"-" but can't have more than one of the string before  the split"-" in a returned combination. So the combination of 'ROOM1-abc' and 'ROOM1-def' is not allowed because 'ROOM1' occurs more than once.

Comment: @Chris: but this means that you don't need all combinations. How can we know what combinations are desired?

Comment: That's the whole issue. Getting all combinations from combn is straight-forward. The challenge is needing to identify the string before the split and if the combination length is 2...n then the string before the split can exist max 1 time in a returned combination whether it's a 2-item combo or 3-item combo. In Python, we populated a dictionary key with the string before the split and then all those items involved were populated into that key's values. We then got all combinations of values via a product of all values (perhaps this is similar to R's expand ?).

Comment: And the resulting combination (at 2-item) is:
```
(('ROOM1-abc', 'ROOM2-lol'),
('ROOM1-abc', 'ROOM3-whatever'),
('ROOM1-def', 'ROOM2-abc'),
('ROOM1-def', 'ROOM2-lol'),
('ROOM1-def', 'ROOM3-whatever'),
('ROOM2-abc', 'ROOM3-whatever'),
('ROOM2-lol', 'ROOM3-whatever'))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to do `combn` on the `list` and return as a `list` of `vector`s

```
library(tidyverse)
combn(lst1, 2, simplify = FALSE) %>%
       map(flatten_chr)
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list('ROOM1-abc',
'ROOM1-def',
'ROOM2-abc',
'ROOM2-lol',
'ROOM3-whatever')
```

Comment: This creates a variable to hold the list, which I initially did not create but it does not address the desired output.

Comment: @Chris Your desired solution seems to be a list of vectors and BTW, the list you showed is not a syntax in R, but from python