# Remove duplicates across columns

Tags: r, duplicates

```
df
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "b" 
 [2,] "a"  "c"
 [3,] "a"  "d"
 [4,] "b"  "a"
 [5,] "b"  "c"
 [6,] "b"  "d" 
 [7,] "c"  "a" 
 [8,] "c"  "b" 
 [9,] "c"  "d"
```

Let's assume have a data.frame like this and I want to remove duplicates in sense of across the column

```
df1
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "b" 
 [2,] "a"  "c"
 [3,] "a"  "d"
 [5,] "b"  "c"
 [6,] "b"  "d" 
 [9,] "c"  "d"
```

I want to end up like this.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028369/removing-duplicate-combinations-irrespective-of-order and the many linked questions in the side bar of that question for variations on this same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `sort`  the elements in each `row` with `apply`, `t`ranspose the output, apply `duplicated` to return a logical vector and use that for subsetting the rows

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df[, 1:2], 1, sort))),]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  "b" 
#[2,] "a"  "c" 
#[3,] "a"  "d" 
#[4,] "b"  "c" 
#[5,] "b"  "d" 
#[6,] "c"  "d"
```

---

or another option is `pmin/pmax`

```
df[!duplicated(cbind(pmin(df[,1], df[,2]), pmax(df[,1], df[,2]))),]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "b", 
"c", "d", "a", "c", "d", "a", "b", "d"), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))
```

Comment: how to alter if there is 3rd column in df but we are only interested in duplication based on column 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @iHermes you can just subset the first two columns.  updated